# Rails specify a required scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

There is a model that has an `active` boolean field. It gets set to true once the record is no longer a draft, and can be used by the system. This in turn requires developers to remember to use `.active` scope is most places to avoid using records that are not ready yet. Unfortunately, forgetting happens.

Some may suggest using a `default_scope`, but this merely changes having to remember to use `.active` to having to remember to use `.unscoped` when the full collection is needed. No, `default_scope` is not the way here.

I imagine functionality that would require that developers be explicit about which group of records they need, and raise otherwise.

For example having these macro calls in the model

```
required_scope :mode
required_scope [:active, :inactive, :everything]

scope :mode, -> (arg) { where(mode: arg) }
```

Would produce this behavior:

```
Model.all #=> RequiredScopeError "Model queries must call .mode, and one of [:active, :inactive, :everything]"
Model.mode(:best) #=> RequiredScopeError "Model queries must call one of [:active, :inactive, :everything]"
Model.mode(:best).active #=> query executes.
```

Does Rails 5+ provide something like this, is there a gem? I could monkeypatch Rails, pointers regarding that are also welcome.

Comment: How about some repository pattern, where the developers must use `ModelRepository` and methods from that instead of the basic `Model.all` methods. That would not stop them from using it obviously, but using the repository would be required way

Comment: I second @Eyeslandic. Changing the behavior of `ActiveRecord`/`ActiveRecord::Relation` in this fashion is not only cumbersome but confusing. You would be better off implementing your own class(es) to create the pattern you are after and then utilizing these classes in your code base rather than direct communication with the model. Not only does this isolate your concerns it will be less fragile during upgrades and will provide far greater code transparency as to why and how these mechanisms were implemented.

Comment: If you are using Pundit for authorization it already has scopes and a mechanism to check if the scopes are used.

Comment: In general, is not a good idea to change the behavior of ActiveRecord unless you really need it, I will suggest a Facade Pattern, you can think of a Facade as a wrapper that manages the complexity of interact with your object/model, it works like a service, that knows how to interact with the data, in this way you can add all the logic of your scopes withing this service and simply call/use the service around the app/api, of course, there are other options but I think this one can be a good fit for you.